# How to implement VS 2010-like floating tabs?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I'm building a tabbed WPF application. I'm planning to put MapPoint control (ActiveX) on one of the tabs. I want to have the option to float this tab just like in VS 2010. The resulting widow must contain the same instance of the MapPoint control (because each instance of the control starts up separate MapPoint instance). Any idea how to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [AvalonDock](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=avalondock).

[image: AvalonDock screenshot]